# Compare each element in two arrays Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, compare

I have two arrays of strings. for example:

```
let arrayFirst: [String] = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"]
let arraySecond: [String] = ["A", "C", "A", "B", "A"]
```

I need to compare this two arrays each element in array and return for every sequence bool state.
For example here will be answer:

```
 let resultArray: [Bool] = [true, false, true, false, true]
```

how to do it better?

Comment: What should the result be if the arrays are of different length? Maybe you could add your own attempt at solving this to clarify what you want to do and also since this is expected when posting a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider using the `zip` function.

```
let resultArray = zip(arrayFirst, arraySecond).map {
    return $0.0 == $0.1
}
```

This will work even you have arrays of different length as `zip` will ignore the additional elements of the longer array.

Comment: Even `.map(==)` should work.

Comment: Yes, but i need to handle false values ​​and true values..